# Can you make values returned by functions be saved as separate variables?

Tags: python, list, class, variables, return

For a large project that I am working on, I have set up two seperate documents: one called `POKEDEX.py`, the other called `TEST.py`. I am attempting to make it so that I am able to take a list (containing sprite data) from a class in POKEDEX, and save them to a variable of some sort in TEST. Here is what the area I'd like to focus on looks like:

```
class POKEDEX
    class i008:
        class front:
            def __str__(self):
                return #really long list contained as string
        class back:
            def __str__(self):
                return #really long list contained as string
```

I then have this for the test code:

```
from POKEDEX import POKEDEX as pkdx

t = pkdx.i008.back()
```

So if I said `print(t)`, it would print the list, but as a string (obviously). What I want to do is to be able to then convert that list back over to being a list, but to do so, I would need the string to be read into its own variable that would be defined in TEST. I've looked through quite a few related posts on here, but none of them actually answer my question.

I will happily attach any extra info that you'll need. I am just starting to learn how classes work and can be used, so it is probably just something I have yet to learn how to do. If it helps to know this, I am using the Python IDLE to code at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just return a list then let its `__str__` method deal with formatting it? I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do. Could you add some more context and example data? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/343832), and the nested classes in `class POKEDEX` don't really make sense without context. BTW welcome to SO!

Comment: when I run it like that, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\TEST.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(t)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)

The classes are just a temporary measure, I am unsure of how else to store this in a different way. Any suggestions?

Also, thanks for the welcome. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. That's not what I meant. `__str__` needs to return a string. I'm talking about replacing `front` and `back` with lists, or something along those lines.

Comment: What format is the sprite data? I've never coded a game.

Comment: Well as it currently stands, this is what the sprite data looks like (I have a function that can read it properly in TEST, also the sprite data is way too long to paste in here, sorry): [[[56],[3]],[[56],[3]],[[56],[3]],[[56],[3]],[[34,2,20],[3,0,3]],[[34,2,20],[3,0,3]],........]]. I have the function return that, but as the code currently stands, that is in quotation marks, so that it can return properly. I want it to be considered as a list somehow. Is that possible? Also, are you saying I could merely turn i008 into a function and define `front` and `back` as variables inside that function?

Comment: I don't know about changing `i008` cause there's not enough context. In any case, my main question is, why are you using a string representation of a list and trying to convert it to a list, instead of just using a list, then getting its string representation as needed?

Comment: I'm using a string representation because it is the only way I have been able to get the data into the other program, at any point. I've changed around the code around a bit, so now it read as: "class POKEDEX: def i008(): front = #data back = #data". However I don't know how to get the front and back variables as defined in there into my other program, as the only thing i can do is return them, which only prints them, and requires them to be strings.

Comment: *"I'm using a string representation because it is the only way I have been able to get the data into the other program, at any point"* - Wait what? I thought you were writing it in that module. How are you getting it in? Have you considered using JSON or pickle?